# What blades are used to cut pepperoni in this video?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I wonder, what blades are used to cut pepperoni in this video?
Pizza making automated line by Picnic:
https://youtu.be/_dCC96BOlDU

Comment: check the manufacturer's website for replacement parts

Answer (score 0):

Most likely ( aka, cheapest that can do the job) 13 Cr plus a little carbon. SAE or AISI grade 420 stainless ( majority of consumer knives , cutlery). Many additional possibilities starting with 13 Cr  and add a pinch of Mo, or V, or W ,etc.